# Does strftime - modify the value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a list that outputs like so:

This works fine, the output is correct:

```
<% @chat_feed.each do |item| %>
    <%= item.created_at %>
<% end %>

Output: 
2011-06-18 00:29:55 UTC
2011-06-18 00:30:01 UTC
2011-06-18 00:30:05 UTC
```

But when I loop through like this, trying to format the datetime format, all the values show up the same. Why? Is this setting something?

```
<% @chat_feed.each do |item| %>
    <%= item.created_at.strftime("%m/%d/%y %l:%d %p") %>
<% end %>

output
06/18/11 12:18 AM
06/18/11 12:18 AM
06/18/11 12:18 AM
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your format is incorrect.  "12:18" is "Hour-of-day:day-of-month", because you've used `%d` for minutes, when what you want is `%M` (uppercase).

Comment: Sorry not sure what the revision should be? What's the update?